# Executing a query in node.js and displaying the data

Tags: html, mysql, node.js, routes, ejs

I am calling a query using the url with a dynamic id. I was able to parse the url and I got the value inside the variable `txt`.

After that I am running a query to select from the table where `id = txt`. Everything looks fine, however, when I try to display the data I am getting empty values. Are there any steps I am missing?

Router:

```
// creating a route to user-edit
router.get('/user-edit', function(req, res, next) {
  var adr = url.parse(req.url,true).query;
  var txt = adr.id;
  var sql2="SELECT * FROM `order_new` WHERE id = ' + txt;
    db.query(sql2, function (err, data, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
  res.render('user-edit', { adr: adr, userData: data});
  });
});
module.exports = router;
```

Views (EJS):

```
<label>Name: </label><input type="text" name="username" placeholder=<%=userData.name %>>
<label>Record: </label><input type="text" name="recordnumber" placeholder=<%=adr.id %>>
```

Comment: Have you tried to output these values inside of a `<pre>` tag? What do you see? Is userData an array?

Comment: Side note: you should use the second form of querying here: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#performing-queries or at minimum escape the values yourself: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values